# Git - Committing from a submodule with a detached HEAD?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following three Repos:

`A`, `B`, and `C`

`B` is a submodule of `A`, and `C` is a submodule of `B`. `C` has a `DETACHED HEAD`.

When I make changes to `B` from INSIDE `A`'s directory, I am able to commit to the `master` branch of `B` just fine. However, when I make changes to `C` from inside:

```
A ->
    B->
        C # Detached Head
```

it does not allow me to push changes to the `master` branch of `C`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`git push` on its own will not work from a detached HEAD.

However, as @ElpieKay points out, you can still push using the `<source object>:<destination ref>` syntax

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: How about `git push origin HEAD:master` from a detached head?

Comment: I stand corrected.  You are correct @ElpieKay.  I'll update my answer...